# where can i write the common or generic functions in the java spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project, where i have following structure:

```
controller
service
serviceImpl
resopository
entity
```

my question is, where can i write the common/generic/library functions, so that i can reuse in all the controller.

```
Example:
1. Calculate age from dob
2. Calculate difference between two days
```

Is there any specific rule to be followed, to write this common function, can you guys throw some light on it.

Thanks,

Comment: I dont know why this question was been downvoted, this may seems to silly question, but so many novice developers or freelance developers, will benefit from this type of questions, where people are working alone or learning without any guidance, will benefit from this type of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open another package like "util" and write your common/generic code there. If there are many classes like that for diffirent kind of stuff, you can open even inner packages (util.calculations etc)

Comment: Thanks for your input